# Read a pdf file from S3 and display it to UI using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, react-pdf

I am trying to read a PDF file stored in AWS S3 and display the file to UI using react-pdf library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) but facing error "Unable to read PDF". The below is the code snippet,

```
    const [file, setFile] = useState("");
        
    useEffect(() => {
        const readFile = async () => {
          const s3Client = new AWS.S3();
          const s3Data = s3Client.getObject(
            {
              Bucket: "Test",
              Key: "file/test.pdf",
            },
            function (err, data) {
              if (err) return err;
              const blbfile = new Blob([data.Body.toString('utf-8')], { type:"application/pdf" });
              blbfile.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
              blbfile.name = "test.pdf";
              
              setFile(window.URL.createObjectURL(blbfile));
            }
          );
        };
        readFile();
      }, []);

  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }
        
  return(<Document file={file} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
           <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>)
```

Comment: Why are you converting the body of the PDF to string in `data.Body.toString('utf-8')`? Also note that you can use promisifed variants of AWS SDK calls e.g. `const data = await s3Client.getObject(params).promise()`.